# Android: pass data from popup window to parent Activity

Tags: android

i want to send smileys from popup window to message body of parent Activity.i am able to set smileys in grid view inside popup window.Can anybody help me?it is something like, when you click on smiley one popup comes with smileys and when you click on that, it goes in message body..

Comment: use concept of interface.

Comment: can you be more precise or can give any example?

Comment: use Like @Gooziec has posted

Answer (score 3):

You may create Interfece that will be implemented by Your Main Activity and passed to PopUp Class

```
public interface SomeInterface

    {
        public void foo();
    }
```

Add SomeInterface object to your PopUp

```
public PopUp extends Fragment
{
 SomeInterface responder;

 ...

 //someheare in your fragment 
 responder.foo();
}
```

and implements SomeInterface in Your MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SomeInterface
{

...
 public void foo()
{
//do whatever
}
```